# I removed something called Unity webapp integration (I don't remember exactly), and now I don't have Unity, how to revert this?

Tags: installation, unity, uninstall, gui

Yesterday I think I removed something called Unity webapp integration (I don't remember exactly) Now when I log in to Ubuntu, only the image of the desktop and its content are displayed, there's no top bar, no sidebar on the left. I'm pretty much unable to do anything.

How can I get it back to normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably while uninstalling webapps you unistalled some important component. So open a terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> or if that doesn't work <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>.

Then type `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: This should work to re-install anything that is missing. If that still doesn't work, please update your question with any other helpful info.